# Comparing two bytes in MIPS

Tags: assembly, branch, mips

I'm trying to make a simple MIPS program work. I want to check if the character inputted by the user is a space. I have defined a variable `space` in my `.data` section. I then take the user input, and use `jal` to call my function which should check this. I load the byte `space` into `$a0` and then want to check whether `$t0` and `$a0` are the same. If they aren't `$t1` should be set to `1` and then I used branch not equal to branch to my other function which prints out the response to the user. However, no matter what character I enter it always branches. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
space: .byte ' '

main:
    #Getting user input 
    li $v0,8
    la $a0,str1
    li $a1, 20
    syscall 
    jal is_space

    #Indicate the end of main function
    li $v0,10
    syscall
is_space: 
    add $t0, $a0, $zero
    lb $a0, space
    sltu $t1, $a0, $t0
    bne $t1, $zero, spaceinput
```

Comment: I'll assume your `syscall` is the kind used by SPIM: `syscall` with `$v0 == 8` reads a *string*. If you want to compare a byte of that string, you need to load it into a register.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to even access the character that was read. It's placed in a buffer at `str1`. Also, if you want to check for equality, why are you using `sltu`? Storing the space in memory is a waste, too.

```
main:
    #Getting user input 
    li $v0,8
    la $a0,str1
    li $a1, 20
    syscall 
    lb $a0, ($a0) # fetch first character entered
    jal is_space

    #Indicate the end of main function
    li $v0,10
    syscall
is_space: 
    li $t0, ' '
    beq $a0, $t0, spaceinput
```